# as in React Hooks to give the initial value an empty object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code

```
export interface Y{
  title: string;
  name: string;
}

const [x, setX] = useState<Y>(Object);
```

But my friends say that this is a bad idea.
Why a bad idea to use this useState(Object)?

Comment: `useState<Y>(Object);` What is this? Are you trying to pass the inbuilt Object prototype as the initial state value?.

Comment: @ Авин Кавиш  var Object: ObjectConstructor  .I myself do not understand what this means. But I get an empty object, the initial state.as I said, my friends scold me for such a cod but cannot explain why this is a bad idea.

Comment: How do you know you get an empty object?

Comment: @Авин Кавиш Watch it.  [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-aryabhata-2wv74)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the thing that I found strange is that you pass `Object` for useState hook.

```js
export interface Y{
  title: string;
  name: string;
}

const [x, setX] = useState<Y>();
```

In that case the type of x is  `Y | undefined`, which is better as now we know that x is empty.

Passing `Object` as you did will make typescript happy, but now you cheat on yourself as typescript won't guard you.

Depending on situation I would suggest to go the first route and leave useState empty, or hardcode object structure e.g.

```
const [x, setX] = useState<Y>({title: '', name: ''});
```

if the question is whether to use useReducer or useState - than I think it all depends on how often you are going to change the object. If the logic is simple enough using useReducer may be an overkill. Also, don't forget that useState is just a wrapper around useReducer hook, afaik.

Comment: my question is this 1 What happens if you write like this `const [x, setX] = useState<Y>(Object)`; 2 Why am I not getting Error?3 difference between  useState<Y>(); and useState<Y>(Object);

Comment: 1. If we have a look at react type definition function `useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];` we see that accepts a function, so Object is considered as function and as you may guess the result of calling `Object` is empty object `{}`
Note: just for fun try this
`class MyClass {};

const [x, setX] = useState(MyClass)`
You will get an error `Cannot call a class as a function`

Comment: I would like to hear the final answer use `useState <Y> (Object);`. This is the wrong way because it can lead to ......?

Comment: Sorry, I think I've answered all of your questions. To sum it up - I consider this a bad idea to write `useState <Y> (Object);` cuz: 

1 - you lose typesafety in typescript;

2 - this is not an obvious code. I bet that even an experienced developer will spend some time to understand what value will be in variable `x`.  And this is my personal advice: you write code for other developers that's why try to make it as readable as possible.

If you think that this code leads to some perf issues and possible errors - than not, It is kinda safe.

Answer (score 3):

`const [x, setX] = useState<Y>(Object);`

This is not valid typescript as the use of the generic parameter `<Y>` makes the type system expect the initial state to be of type `Y` (or null), making the only valid input, `useState({ title: '', name: '' })` or `useState(null)`

Also, the useState hook does not perform partial updates on state.

```
export interface Y{
  title: string;
  name: string;
}

const [x, setX] = useState<Y>({ title: 'Mr', name: 'Jack' });

setX({ name: 'John' })  // <-- title: undefined

setX({ ...x, name: 'john' }) // <-- You will have to do this instead
```

Perfomance and reasoning wise this is okay for small objects, but when you have a large state object, state management gets hard. But breaking state into lots of variables makes code verbose. In that case, you can use a [reducer hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for me

```
const [selectedAccount, setselectedAccount] = useState(Object);
```

Comment: hmm  didn't work