# Typescript complaining when calling a method from React useState initialized with an empty object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

In the main App component I have an event handler that passes an onSubmit and onClose callback to the onOpenDialog function

**App.ts**

```js
const App = () => {
  const { onOpenDialog, onCloseDialog } = useDialog()
  
  const onOpenModal = () => {
    // Open the Dialog and pass callbacks
    onOpenDialog({
      onSubmit: (data: any) => {
        // ... CRUD operation
        onCloseDialog()
      },
      onCancel: onCloseDialog
    })

  return <button onClick={onOpenModal}>Open</button>
}
```

The onOpenDialog function comes from the useDialog hook which stores the callback in the Dialog state.

This state is initialized with an empty object (`{}`). It is populated when the modal is open and reseted to its initial value (`{}`) when the modal is closed.

**useDialog.ts**

```js
const useDialog = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [dialogState, setDialogState] = useState<object>({})

  const onOpenDialog = (config?: object): void => {
    setOpen(true)
    if (isObject(config) && !isEmpty(config)) {
      setDialogState(config!)
    }
  }
  
  const onCloseDialog = (): void => {
    setOpen(false)
    if (!isEmpty(dialogState)) {
      setDialogState({})
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, I have a hook for my modal form component that exports two handlers (onSubmit and onCancel) which will be called in the modal form component

**useModalForm.ts**

```js
const useModalForm = () => {
  const { dialogState } = useDialog()

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    dialogState.onSubmit(data) // Property 'onSubmit' does not exist on type 'object'
  }

  return {
    onSubmit: onSubmit,
    onCancel: dialogState.onCancel,
  }
}
```

I can't call `dialogState.onSubmit(data)` because typescript complains that onSubmit doesn't exist in type 'object' (which I understand)

How can I - in Typescript - set the initial/closed state to `{}` and populate it with whatever callback or data I pass when the modal is open.

I tried to type useState with an interface of the signature of the expected state but when I close the modal, I can't reset the dialogConfig to `{}` without Typescript complaining.

Comment: you could use something like Record<string, any> as type, instead of object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and tried the same solutions.
Here's what I found in the [React+TypeScript Cheatsheets](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#usestate):

#### Approach 1

Create a type for the expected state then "explicitly declare the type, and use a union type".

```
type IDialogState = { /* Describe the shape of your state */ };

const [dialogState, setDialogState] = React.useState<IDialogState | null>(null);
```

#### Approach 2

"You can also use type assertions if a state is initialized soon after setup and always has a value after:"

```
type IDialogState = { /* Describe the shape of your state */ };

const [dialogState, setDialogState] = React.useState<IDialogState>({} as IDialogState);
```

"This temporarily 'lies' to the TypeScript compiler that {} is of type IDialogState. You should follow up by setting the user state — if you don't, the rest of your code may rely on the fact that user is of type IDialogState and that may lead to runtime errors."

*Source: [React+TypeScript Cheatsheets](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#usestate)
(variable names adapted)*

---

Related:

- [as in React Hooks to give the initial value an empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526974/as-in-react-hooks-to-give-the-initial-value-an-empty-object)
- https://jsramblings.com/how-to-use-usestate-hook-in-react-with-typescript/
- https://www.carlrippon.com/typed-usestate-with-typescript/